# binding to Dictionary in Xamarin

Tags: dictionary, xamarin, xamarin.forms, binding

My model looks like this:

```
class Puzzle
{
     public string Name {get; set;}
     public string Id {get; set;}
     public PuzzleKind Kind {get; set;}
     public Dictionary<string, string> Details {get; set;}
}
```

The Details field is different fro my different Puzzles. In the UI representation of those I use a DateTemplateSelector to choose what template to use one data template or another depending on the PuzzleKind. It works like a charm.

I bind to the Name, Id and Kind, no problem. My Problem is how to bind to the Details["key"] ??

I know what kind of Details will arrive depending on the Kind of Puzzle, I created a DataTemplate like this :

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myFirstTemplate">
    <ViewCell>
        <Grid ... with definitions...>
             <Label Text="{Binding Path=Details["expectedKey"],
                    Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}"/>
        </Grid>
    </ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
```

This code just throws and unhandled exception during startup ... My Question is how to bind to this, and also how to change the color of the font depending on the incomming value

Comment: Each puzzle has multiple details?

Comment: yup, and a different number and type (although they all come in a json string)

Answer (score 4):

Details[expectedKey] (without the quotes) worked for me...

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just binding to the json and using a parameter into the converter to know what of the expected parameters will need to be used. Like this:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Path=Details, Converter={StaticResource FirstClockConverter}, ConverterParameter=expectedKey}"/>
```

Then in the code behind I handle the thing like this :

```
public class FirstClockConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {            
        return (value as Dictionary<string,string>)[parameter as string];
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The benefit here is that I can tweak the conversion depending on the parameter (knowing the type of the expectedParamenter or I can even check other values from the static properties of my main model in order to show proper feedback in the screen. With only one converter for all bindings.

Answer (score 0):

If the "expectedKey" is hardcoded then you could do it the next way:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Path=Details.[expectedKey]}" />
```

The syntax is a bit tricky, but not that bad.

You could also iterate through a Dictionary the next way:

```
<ListView
    ItemsSource="{Binding Details}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding Key}" Detail="{Binding Value}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I ended up sending the expected key as a parameter to the ValueConverter. Would you favor your solution to this ?

Comment: Sounds like a working solution. Other than that it is hard to say what will fit better, it is all up to your needs. I just shared few Dictionary binding examples to give you an idea.